# Nuget Package Clash on Different Dependency Version

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play-services, xamarin.forms.maps

I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Maps and Microsoft.AppCenter.Push in my PCL project. Lately I tried to update my Push to latest version, but it's clashing with the Maps because different version of Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base is expected.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   NU1107 Version conflict detected for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.
>   Install/reference Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 71.1610.0 directly
>   to project XXX.Android to resolve this issue.
>
> XXX.Android -> Microsoft.AppCenter.Push 2.5.0 ->
>   Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.0 -> Xamarin.Firebase.Iid 71.1710.0
>   -> Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.Interop 71.1601.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (>= 71.1610.0)
>
> XXX.Android -> Xamarin.Forms.Maps 4.3.0.947036 ->
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.1 ->
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (= 60.1142.1).

Push is expecting version 71 while Maps is expecting version 60. May I know how to resolve this and I'm curious why cannot the Maps use the later version? Is it not backward compatible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have reproduce this problem as you said.

Accoriding to the error log, we know that the problem is that though the `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` Nuget  have been updated to a newer version, but the package (`Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base`) in this nuget hasn't been updated synchronously to the later version( `71.1610.0`). It should be an issue of this Nuget. And we can report it as a bug here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

For now, in order to keep the code working properly,what we can do is keep the two Nuget versions in sync.
Just install nuget `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push 2.1.1` and nuget `Xamarin.Forms.Maps 4.3.0.947036`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

If you read the comments, there is [one](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8633#issuecomment-559005041) saying that you can install dependencies manually.

In this case, by visiting the [NuGet repo for Xamarin.Forms.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/4.5.0.142-pre1) you can see in the dependencies list that it requires *Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps*.

Just make sure you already have dependencies installed, or simply add them to your Android solution (I added also *Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat*).

By following these steps, I'm able to run both Xamarin.Forms.Maps (v4.4.0.991477) and Microsoft.AppCenter.Push (v2.6.4).

---

There is an issue on the GitHub relate repo and seems to be fixed.

Refer to following link please

[NuGet version conflict between Xamarin.Froms.Maps and Microsoft.AppCenter.Push](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8633)

You can check the whole evolution of the issue.

Comment: What is the solution?